# Fabric not working with cron job

Tags: python, cron, fabric, pexpect

I'm trying to run a deploy script using [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) and Fabric. This is what is happening:

```
$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 04 * * * /bin/bash /home/pedregal/Deploy/deploy.sh

$ ls -l
total 20
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pedregal pedregal  239 Nov 11 09:00 deploy.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pedregal pedregal  271 Nov  9 21:33 expectfile.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pedregal pedregal  900 Nov 10 07:28 fabfile.py
```

**deploy.sh** (I'm a total shell scripting newbie, bear with me)

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPECT_FILE=/home/pedregal/Deploy/expectfile.py
LOG_FILE=/home/pedregal/Deploy/deploy.log

touch $LOG_FILE
python $EXPECT_FILE > $LOG_FILE 2>&1
mail -s "Auto-update log" cbustios@elpedregalsa.com < $LOG_FILE
```

**expectfile.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pexpect
import sys

child = pexpect.spawn('fab piura deploy', echo=False)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect('user:')
child.sendline('cesarbustios')
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline('************')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

**fabfile.py**

```
# -*- coding:  utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import with_statement
import os
from os.path import join, dirname

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from fabric.api import cd, env, prefix, run, sudo, warn_only


DOTENV_PATH = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
GESTAGRO_PATH = '/home/pedregal/Projects/gestagro/gestagro/'
VENV_PATH = '/home/pedregal/Environments/gestagro/venv/bin/activate'
ACTIVATE_VENV = 'source %s' % (VENV_PATH)
load_dotenv(DOTENV_PATH)


def piura():
    env.hosts = [
        'pedregal@192.168.5.20:22',
    ]
    env.passwords = {
        'pedregal@192.168.5.20:22': os.environ.get('PASSWORD_PIURA'),
    }


def deploy():
    with cd(GESTAGRO_PATH), prefix(ACTIVATE_VENV), warn_only():
        run('hg pull -u')
        run('python manage.py migrate --no-color')
        run('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --no-color')
        sudo('nginx -s reload')
        sudo('supervisorctl restart gestagro')
```

If I run `deploy.sh` manually it runs perfectly fine, however, I'm receiving an email with the following traceback from the cron job:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pedregal/Deploy/expectfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    child = pexpect.spawn('fab piura deploy', echo=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 194, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 267, in _spawn
    'executable: %s.' % self.command)
pexpect.exceptions.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: fab.
```

I thought the installation of Fabric was system-wide, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cronjob doesn't run load `.bash_profile` nor your `.bashrc`, these are source'd by your shell. But `cron` does **not** run through your shell so you have to setup the required environment variables (e.g. `PATH`) manually from the running script.

Comment: So, adding `source /home/pedregal/.profile` in my shell script would be enough?

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I've used before. But note that you can add environment variables to all jobs by defining them at the top of your `crontab` file. As an alternative you could set the `SHELL` variable to point to the bash executable and then set the `BASH_ENV` to your script to have a common environment for all jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with fabric and python

me@local $ crontab cron_file.txt

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

- - - - - cd /home/me/scriptz && fab server_backup